# c# reflecting on properties or other member types

Tags: c#, class, reflection, properties

I'm using a tool called filehelpers, which defines a class on the fly for purposes of file import.  The class file might look like:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst(1)]
public class TestNoPrimaryKey
{

[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
[FieldQuoted()]
public decimal Value;

[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForRead, MultilineMode.AllowForRead)]
public String aString;

}
```

This is correctly created in code from what I can see.  Next I need to create a datatable in a comparable format, so I can do a SQL insert.  Through kind help on SO I have this code which accepts the type (defined above) and purports to generate the typed datatable columns for me:

```
public static DataTable TypeToEmptyDataTable(Type myType)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    foreach (PropertyInfo info in myType.GetProperties())
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not find any properties and returns a datatable with no columns.  Now I'm thinking - if the get; set; etc isn't specified in the class maybe they aren't 'properties' per se.  Maybe getMembers is what I need?  I tried that but returning info.MemberType did not work.

Any thoughts on how to get the names/types out of my class?  I don't believe I can add the get/set because that class layout is required by the filehelpers tool I'm using.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't written any *properties* in the code above - you've declared *fields*. The `get` and `set` does indeed make a very significant difference :)

If you want to get fields, just use `GetFields` - but I'd recommend that you make them properties instead. Properties work better in terms of binding etc, as well as generally being a better *start* towards encapsulation.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks Jon.  If I was using the class normally I'd certainly go with properties, but since its purpose in this case is pretty much a file definition, the getfields sounds great.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

**This addition to @Jon Skeet answer ...........**

Read value of your fields like this :

Right now you are reading properties not fileds of the classes

```
Type type = typeof(ReflectionTest); // Get type pointer
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(); // Obtain all fields
foreach (var field in fields) // Loop through fields
{
      ///you code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use get field  with binding flags

```
myType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty);
```

Comment: I haven't looked at these but will check them out.  Thanks :)